# How to build Perfect Hash in C++?

Tags: c++, hash

I'd like to know how to build a Perfect Hash in C++.

Perfect Hash is such a hash that 1) Has no collisions at all, 2) Is built only for fixed set of values, 3) Maps set of N values to a range of numbers of `0 .. N * 1.23 - 1`, i.e. it maps not to numbers till N, but till some bigger multiple of N, like `N * 1.23`.

I've read [this Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) article about Perfect Hash.

And decided to post this short question only to send my own Answer.

So I don't provide any Minimal Reproducible Example, only because answer is fully contained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have set S of N integer elements. We want to perfect-hash this set.

There are different ways of building perfect hash. But one way, according to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function), is following way:

1. First we choose some function `g(x) = k * x mod p mod n`, where P is some quite large prime. And K is some random constant. N is number of elements in a set.
2. Then we map through g(x) all elements of a set, these elements map to some integers in a range 0..N-1 which may collide. Collided integers form separate buckets.
3. We create infinite amount of Hash functions. For example in my below C++ code I use same as g(x) functions equal to `Hash[i](x) = RandomConstant[i] * x mod Prime[i] mod M`, where `M = N * 1.23`, here `1.23` is some small constant, it can be something like `1.2-1.5`.
4. Each bucket `B_i` is hashed separately in such a way that it forms set `K_i = Hash[l](x)` for `x` in `B_i`, so that `l` is minimal and `|K_i| = |B_i|`, and `K_i` doesn't intersect with any previous `K_i`. Each minimal found `l` is stored as `sigma(i) = l`.
5. `sigma(i)` is compressed into bit vector in such a way that we can get value `l = sigma(i)` in `O(1)` time. Using any compact bit packing technique like [Gamma Coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elias_gamma_coding) or [Unary Coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_coding).
6. Finally, to get perfect hash of value `x` we do `PerfectHash(x) = Hash[sigma(g(x))](x)`.

Full code below. It generates N random numbers, then perfect hashes them and finally outputs amount of bits per number.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/v4zd6bKzK)

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <bit>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <array>

#define ASSERT_MSG(cond, msg) { if (!(cond)) throw std::runtime_error("Assertion (" #cond ") failed at line " + std::to_string(__LINE__) + "! Msg: '" + std::string(msg) + "'."); }
#define ASSERT(cond) ASSERT_MSG(cond, "")
#define DASSERT_MSG(cond, msg) ASSERT_MSG(cond, msg)
#define DASSERT(cond) DASSERT_MSG(cond, "")

using u8 = uint8_t;
using u32 = uint32_t;
using u64 = uint64_t;

template <typename T>
bool IsPrime(T const & n) {
    if (n % 2 == 0)
        return false;
    for (size_t d = 3; d * d <= n; d += 2)
        if (n % d == 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}

template <typename T>
T NextPrime(T const & i) {
    if (i <= 2) return 2;
    for (T j = i | 1;; j += 2)
        if (IsPrime(j))
            return j;
}

class BitVector {
    static size_t constexpr index_block = 1 << 9;
    
public:
    BitVector() {}
    BitVector(size_t size) : size_(size), bits_((size_ + 7) / 8) {}
    void Clear() {
        size_ = 0;
        bits_.clear();
        index_.clear();
    }
    size_t Size() const { return size_; }
    bool Get(size_t i) const {
        return (bits_[i / 8] >> (i % 8)) & u8(1);
    }
    void Set(size_t i, bool val = true) {
        if (val)
            bits_[i / 8] |= u8(1) << (i % 8);
        else
            bits_[i / 8] &= ~(u8(1) << (i % 8));
    }
    void Push(bool val) {
        ++size_;
        if (size_ - 1 >= bits_.size() * 8)
            bits_.resize((size_ + 7) / 8);
        Set(size_ - 1, val);
    }
    void Index() {
        index_.clear();
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size_; i += index_block) {
            size_t sum = 0;
            size_t const portion = std::min(index_block, size_ - i);
            for (size_t k = i; k < i + portion; k += 64)
                if (i + portion - k >= 64)
                    sum += std::popcount(*(u64*)&bits_[k / 8]);
                else {
                    u64 x = 0;
                    std::memcpy(&x, &bits_[k / 8], bits_.size() - k / 8);
                    sum += std::popcount(x);
                }
            index_.push_back(index_.empty() ? sum : (index_.back() + sum));
        }
    }
    size_t Select1(size_t idx) const {
        size_t const d = std::distance(index_.data(), std::upper_bound(index_.data(), index_.data() + index_.size(), idx));
        ASSERT_MSG(d < index_.size(), "idx " + std::to_string(idx));
        size_t const prev_sum = d == 0 ? 0 : index_[d - 1], hi = std::min<size_t>(size_, index_block * (d + 1));
        size_t csum = 0, i = 0;
        u64 word = 0;
        for (i = index_block * d; i < hi; i += 64) {
            size_t const portion = std::min<size_t>(hi - i, 64);
            size_t word_sum = 0;
            if (portion == 64)
                word = *(u64*)&bits_[i / 8];
            else {
                word = 0;
                std::memcpy(&word, &bits_[i / 8], bits_.size() - i / 8);
            }
            word_sum = std::popcount(word);
            if (prev_sum + csum + word_sum > idx)
                break;
            csum += word_sum;
        }
        size_t sum0 = 0;
        while (true) {
            size_t const i1 = std::countr_zero(word);
            ASSERT(i1 < 64);
            if (prev_sum + csum + sum0 >= idx) {
                ASSERT(prev_sum + csum + sum0 == idx);
                ASSERT(Get(i + i1));
                return i + i1;
            }
            word &= word - 1;
            ++sum0;
        }
    }
    std::string Dump() const {
        std::string r;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size_; ++i)
            r.append(1, Get(i) ? '1' : '0');
        return r;
    }
    u64 Word(size_t i) const {
        return (*(u64*)&bits_[i / 8]) >> (i % 8);
    }
    
private:
    size_t size_ = 0;
    std::vector<u8> bits_;
    std::vector<size_t> index_;
};

class GammaBitVector {
    static size_t constexpr index_block = 1 << 7;
    
public:
    template <typename T>
    void GammaEncodeVec(std::vector<T> const & nums) {
        for (auto n: nums) {
            auto [x, b] = GammaEncode(std::max<size_t>(n, 1) - 1);
            //std::cout << n << ": " << b << " " << x << std::endl;
            for (size_t i = 0; i < b; ++i) {
                bv_.Push(bool(x & 1));
                x >>= 1;
            }
        }
        //std::cout << "GammaEncodedVec " << bv_.Size() << std::endl;
        //std::cout << bv_.Dump() << std::endl << std::endl;
    }
    void Index() {
        size_t i = 0, cnt = 0;
        while (i < bv_.Size()) {
            auto const [n, ebits, dbits] = GammaDecode(bv_.Word(i));
            ++cnt;
            i += ebits;
            if (cnt < index_block && i < bv_.Size())
                continue;
            index_.push_back(i);
            cnt = 0;
        }
    }
    size_t Get(size_t i) const {
        size_t j = i / index_block * index_block, sum = i / index_block > 0 ? index_.at(i / index_block - 1) : 0;
        while (sum < bv_.Size()) {
            auto const [n, ebits, dbits] = GammaDecode(bv_.Word(sum));
            if (j >= i)
                return n + 1;
            ++j;
            sum += ebits;
        }
        ASSERT(false);
    }
    size_t Size() const { return bv_.Size(); }
    size_t GetBitOffset(size_t i) const {
        size_t j = i / index_block * index_block, sum = i / index_block > 0 ? index_.at(i / index_block - 1) : 0;
        while (sum < bv_.Size()) {
            auto const [n, ebits, dbits] = GammaDecode(bv_.Word(sum));
            if (j >= i)
                return sum;
            ++j;
            sum += ebits;
        }
        ASSERT(false);
    }
    
private:
    static u64 Shl(u64 w, size_t cnt) {
        return cnt >= 64 ? u64(0) : (w << cnt);
    }
    static u64 Shr(u64 w, size_t cnt) {
        return cnt >= 64 ? u64(0) : (w >> cnt);
    }
    static u64 Mask(size_t n) {
        return n >= 64 ? ~u64(0) : (u64(1) << n) - 1;
    }
    static size_t NumBits(u64 n) {
        return 64 - std::countl_zero(n);
    }
    static std::tuple<u64, size_t> GammaEncode(u64 n) {
        ++n;
        DASSERT(n != 0);
        size_t const nbits = NumBits(n);
        static auto lo = []{
            std::array<u32, 32> r{};
            for (size_t i = 0; i < r.size(); ++i)
                r[i] = u32(1) << i;
            return r;
        }();
        size_t const rnbits = nbits - 1;
        DASSERT(rnbits < lo.size());
        return std::make_tuple((Shl(n & Mask(rnbits), nbits) | u64(lo[rnbits])), rnbits + nbits);
    }
    static std::tuple<u64, size_t, size_t> GammaDecode(u64 n) {
        static size_t constexpr c_tab_bits = 8;
        static auto tab = []{
            std::array<u8, (1 << c_tab_bits)> r{};
            for (size_t i = 0; i < r.size(); ++i) {
                size_t j = i, sr = 0;
                if (i == 0)
                    sr = 0xFF;
                else
                    while (!bool(j & 1)) {
                        ++sr;
                        j >>= 1;
                    }
                r[i] = u8(sr);
            }
            return r;
        }();
        size_t cnt = tab[n & Mask(c_tab_bits)];
        if (cnt == 0xFF) {
            ASSERT(n != 0);
            cnt = 0;
            u64 m = n;
            while (!bool(m & 1)) {
                ++cnt;
                m >>= 1;
            }
            ASSERT(cnt <= 31);
        }
        return std::make_tuple(u64((((n >> (cnt + 1)) & Mask(cnt)) | (u64(1) << cnt)) - 1), size_t(2 * cnt + 1), size_t(cnt + 1));
    }
    
    BitVector bv_;
    std::vector<size_t> index_;
};

class PerfectHash {
public:
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function
    
    void Build(std::vector<u64> const & nums) {
        size_t const n = nums.size();
        m_ = 1.5 * n;
        n_ = n;
        primes_.clear();
        primes_.push_back({rng_(), NextPrime(n_)});
        primes_.push_back({rng_(), NextPrime(m_)});
        std::vector<std::vector<size_t>> Bs(n);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            Bs[g(nums[i])].push_back(nums[i]);
            //std::cout << "i " << i << ": " << nums[i] << ": " << g(nums[i]) << ", ";
        }
        //std::cout << std::endl;
        std::vector<u64> K;
        BitVector Tb(m_);
        std::vector<u32> sigma_l(n);
        size_t max_bucket_size = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            auto const & B = Bs.at(i);
            max_bucket_size = std::max<size_t>(max_bucket_size, B.size());
            if (B.empty())
                continue;
            size_t l = 0;
            for (l = 1; l < 10'000; ++l) {
                bool exists = false;
                K.clear();
                for (size_t iB = 0; iB < B.size(); ++iB) {
                    auto const j = B[iB];
                    auto const h = HashFunc(l, j);
                    if (Tb.Get(h)) {
                        exists = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    for (auto k: K)
                        if (k == h) {
                            exists = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    if (exists)
                        break;
                    K.push_back(h);
                }
                if (!exists)
                    break;
            }
            ASSERT(l < 10'000);
            sigma_l[i] = l;
            for (auto j: K)
                Tb.Set(j);
        }
        sigma_bv_.Clear();
        //std::cout << "MaxBucket " << max_bucket_size << std::endl;
        //std::cout << "Sigma: ";
        for (size_t i = 0; i < sigma_l.size(); ++i) {
            auto const l = sigma_l[i];
            //std::cout << l << ", ";
            sigma_bv_.Push(1);
            for (size_t i = 0; i + 1 < l; ++i)
                sigma_bv_.Push(0);
        }
        //std::cout << std::endl;
        sigma_gbv_.GammaEncodeVec(sigma_l);
        sigma_gbv_.Index();
        //std::cout << "Sigma from GBV: ";
        for (size_t i = 0; i < sigma_l.size(); ++i) {
            //std::cout << sigma_gbv_.Get(i) << ", ";
            ASSERT_MSG(std::max<size_t>(1, sigma_l[i]) == sigma_gbv_.Get(i), "i " + std::to_string(i) + " sigma_l " + std::to_string(std::max<size_t>(1, sigma_l[i])) + " sigma_Get(i) " + std::to_string(sigma_gbv_.Get(i)) + " sigma_GetOff(i) " + std::to_string(sigma_gbv_.GetBitOffset(i)) + " sigma_GetOff(i - 1) " + std::to_string(sigma_gbv_.GetBitOffset(i - 1)));
        }
        //std::cout << std::endl;
        sigma_bv_.Index();
        for (size_t i = 0; i < sigma_bv_.Size(); ++i) {
            //std::cout << (sigma_bv_.Get(i) ? "1" : "0");
        }
        //std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    size_t Hash(u64 const & x) {
        return HashFunc(Sigma(g(x)), x);
    }
    size_t NumBits() const {
        return sigma_gbv_.Size();
    }
    size_t HashFunc(size_t i, u64 const & x) {
        while (i >= primes_.size())
            primes_.push_back({rng_(), NextPrime(primes_.back().second + 1)});
        auto const [k, p] = primes_[i];
        auto v = (k * x) % p;
        size_t const mod = i == 0 ? n_ : m_;
        while (v >= mod)
            v -= mod;
        return v;
    }
    size_t g(u64 const & x) {
        return HashFunc(0, x);
    }
    size_t Sigma(size_t i) {
        size_t const i1 = sigma_gbv_.Get(i);
        //std::cout << "Sigma: " << i << ": " << i1 << std::endl;
        return i1;
        
        /*
        size_t cnt = 0;
        for (size_t i = i1 + 1, size = sigma_bv_.Size(); i < size; ++i, ++cnt) {
            std::cout << i << " (" << std::boolalpha << sigma_bv_.Get(i) << "), ";
            if (sigma_bv_.Get(i))
                break;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl << "Val: " << (cnt + 1) << std::endl;
        return cnt + 1;
        */
    }
    size_t N() const { return n_; }
    size_t M() const { return m_; }
    
private:
    std::mt19937_64 rng_{123};
    size_t n_ = 0, m_ = 0;
    BitVector sigma_bv_;
    GammaBitVector sigma_gbv_;
    std::vector<std::pair<u64, u64>> primes_;
};

int main() {
    try {
        std::mt19937_64 rng{123};
        std::vector<u64> nums(1 << 17);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i)
            nums[i] = rng();
        PerfectHash ph;
        ph.Build(nums);
        std::cout << "Nums " << nums.size() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "PerfectHash Bits " << ph.NumBits() << ", " << std::setprecision(3)
            << (double(ph.NumBits()) / nums.size()) << " bits/num" << std::endl;
        std::unordered_map<u64, u64> hashes;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i) {
            //std::cout << "i " << i << std::endl;
            auto const hash = ph.Hash(nums[i]);
            if (i < 16) {
                //std::cout << nums[i] << ": " << hash << std::endl;
            }
            ASSERT(hash < ph.M());
            ASSERT_MSG(!hashes.count(hash),
                "i " + std::to_string(i) + " nums[i] " + std::to_string(nums[i]) +
                " hash " + std::to_string(hash) + " g(x) " + std::to_string(ph.g(nums[i])) +
                " sigma " + std::to_string(ph.Sigma(ph.g(nums[i]))) +
                " hash_func " + std::to_string(ph.HashFunc(ph.Sigma(ph.g(nums[i])), nums[i])) +
                " prev_i " + std::to_string(hashes.at(hash)) + " nums[hashes.at(hash)] " +
                std::to_string(nums[hashes.at(hash)]) + " prev_g(x) " +
                std::to_string(ph.g(nums[hashes.at(hash)])) + " prev_sigma " +
                std::to_string(ph.Sigma(ph.g(nums[hashes.at(hash)]))) + " prev_hash_func " +
                std::to_string(ph.HashFunc(ph.Sigma(ph.g(nums[hashes.at(hash)])), nums[hashes.at(hash)]))
            );
            hashes[hash] = i;
        }
        ASSERT(hashes.size() == nums.size());
        return 0;
    } catch (std::exception const & ex) {
        std::cout << "Exception: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Console Output:

```
Nums 131072
PerfectHash Bits 244430, 1.86 bits/num
```